# What's the best way move WP website from one folder to another folder?

Tags: database, migration

I have a WordPress website in a server, the domain like this

www.myname.com/test/

Now I want move this website to root folder, the domain name will change to

www.myname.com

What's the best way to do it?
As I know, I will install a new WordPress in server root dictionary then important a the XML file which export from the old WordPress website, then fix all the broken links,images,plugins and so on.

I try to link the new website to the old database in wp-config.php, but doesn't work.

Comment: Just move your wordpress files to myname.com/test to myname.com..Export the database. open database in editor like notepad ,dream weaver etc,. find and repalce www.myname.com/test with www.myname.com.with replace all option in editor. uplaod the db . thats it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.